# .NET 5.0 application not getting environment variables from docker run

Tags: linux, docker, environment-variables, .net-5

I have tried almost every solution I could find on the internet, but nothing has worked.

In my .Net 5.0 application, I am trying to override values for 'IP' and 'Port' in my appsettings.json file using environment variables with the 'docker run' command on Linux.

This is my appsettings.json file:

```
{
    "Logging": {
        "IncludeScopes": false,
        "LogLevel": {
            "Default": "Information",
            "System": "Information",
            "Microsoft": "Information"
        }
    },
    "IPSettings": {
        "IP": "192.168.230.131",
        "Port": "10080"
    }
}
```

This is my Dockerfile (I have tried without using the 'ENV' lines as well):

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
ENV IPSettings__IP='192.168.230.131'
ENV IPSettings__Port='10080'

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["HostServer.csproj", "."]
COPY ["QuicktronWrapper/QuicktronWrapper.csproj", "QuicktronWrapper/"]
RUN dotnet restore "./HostServer.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/."
RUN dotnet build "HostServer.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "HostServer.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "HostServer.dll"]
```

I have also added environment variables to the configuration, like below:

```
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                    .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
                    .AddEnvironmentVariables();

    IConfigurationRoot configuration = builder.Build();
```

I am certainly able to get these values from appsettings.json, because I can run the application without issues on Windows, by launching it from Visual Studio on IIS.

Now, when I try to build the docker image on Linux and run it, the values I provide in the 'docker run' command aren't being passed to my application.

The following are variants of the command I used, but none seem to be working:

```
docker run -it -p 4000:9999 --name HostServer hostserver \
-e "IPSettings:IP"="192.168.247.131" \
-e "IPSettings:Port"="10080"


docker run -e ASPNETCORE_IPSettings__IP="192.168.247.131" \
-e ASPNETCORE_IPSettings__Port="10080" \
-it -p 4000:9999 --name HostServer hostserver


docker run -e IPSettings__IP="192.168.247.131" \
-e IPSettings__Port="10080" \
-it -p 4000:9999 --name HostServer hostserver
```

I have been struggling to fix this for more than a couple of days now. What am I missing here?

Also, if I replace the values in apsettings.json with the values I need and then use the following command:

```
docker run -it -p 4000:9999 --name HostServer hostserver
```

it runs perfectly on Linux, which means the problem is definitely with the way I am passing the environment variables.

Comment: Looks OK. Try printing out the configuration from your dotnet program as described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#display-environment-variables

Comment: See if the environment variables are reaching the container: `docker run --rm -it --entrypoint /bin/bash HostServer` - then run `env`

Comment: @JevonKendon

Thank you, I did that and it looks like the environment variables are not reaching the container.

It shows IPSettings__IP=192.168.230.131, but it should be showing IPSettings__IP=192.168.247.131

Comment: `docker run -it -e IPSettings__IP="192.168.247.131" --entrypoint /bin/bash --name HostServer hostserver` should work; at least, I have the equivalent on my terminal here. Docker can be particular about parameter order. Try this specific order.

Comment: Try a new, made up environment variable, like "Curious=Programmer"

Comment: Environment looks fine.  This type of issue is almost always because the configuration binding is wrong and *not* anything related to docker.  You will get more help by including details about how you are doing the configuration binding and your `Program.cs`/`Startup.cs`.

Comment: @JevonKendon

Thank you, you were right. It was the order of passing parameters. After using the command you specified, it works.

Comment: @JevonKendon Are you able to answer the question with your solution, so that I can mark it as 'answered' and upvote your answer?

Comment: Great. Admittedly it was a stab in the dark. When I changed the order on my end it made no difference. But there you go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks fine.

Something of the form:

```
docker run -it -e IPSettings__IP="192.168.247.131" --entrypoint /bin/bash --name HostServer hostserver
```

should work -  at least, I have the equivalent on my terminal here.

Docker can be particular about parameter order. Try the specific order in the example I provided.